# Issues stopping a service

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I have a broadcastreceiver called `"Callreceiver"` that will listen when a call comes in  it will start a service called `"MyService"`, which is actually the `SensorEventListener` so I can do something when the phone is at a certain position.
OK, everything is working, but when I hang up the phone call I want to end the service `"MyService"`, I try `context.stopService(i);` but it did not work. Then I try `this.stopService(null);` and it does end the service, but only because I get a big error.

My question:
What is the proper way to stop a service through the broadcastreceiver?

Thank You in Advance.

```
package com.example.enablebtwithorientation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;


public class Callreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
String TAG="IncomingInterceptCombo";
static boolean isRinging=false;
int x=0; float roll_angle=0;
int goin_50=0, goin_30=0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Ringer", "ringer started");
        Intent i=new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            Log.d("Ringer", "ringing");
            isRinging = true;
            context.startService(i);                
        }

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Log.d("Ringer", "hanging up");
            isRinging = false;
            //context.stopService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
protected static final ContextWrapper context = null;
MediaPlayer player;
public SensorManager mSensorManager;
public Sensor mOrientation;
public static float x, y, z;
public AudioManager amanager;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mOrientation = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);        
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mOrientation, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    Log.d(TAG, "register sensor");
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float azimuth_angle = event.values[0];
    float pitch_angle = event.values[1];
    float roll_angle = event.values[2];
   Log.d(TAG, "roll_angle: " +roll_angle);

   if(roll_angle>60){Toast.makeText(this, "roll angle over 60" + roll_angle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   this.stopService(null);// works, but not in a good way
   }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stopSelf()` instead of `stopService(null)` from onSensorChanged method.